# Python: Why does my code have a syntax error?

Tags: python, except

```
    # Handle all the exceptions!
#Setup
actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}

def get_last_name():
    try:
        return actor["last_name"]
    except KeyError:
        return "Cleese"

#Test code
get_last_name()
print "All exceptions caught! Good job!"
print "The actor's last name is %s" % get_last_name()
```

Hi guys, could you please tell me why I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~learnpythonjail/3.368780930138799213/main.py", line 77, in execute_python
    exec(code, {})
  File "<string>", line 9
    except SyntaxError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried all types of error catching and it still produces a syntax error.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: That's not caused by any of the code you have posted. Post the code that contains the `except SyntaxError:`. There is probably a missing parenthesis or bracket on the preceding line.

Comment: @kindall: to my eyes, it looks like the `except SyntaxError:` line is part of the code for whatever tutorial tool he's using ("learnpythonjail" is suggestive) and not something the OP wrote.

Comment: This is either a mixing of tabs and spaces, or you are using a character that is blank, but not tab or a space. (Like a non-breaking space, for example).

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing tabs and spaces. Your code is:

```
# Handle all the exceptions!
#Setup
actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}

def get_last_name():
····try:
····――――――return actor["last_name"]
――――――except KeyError:
········return "Cleese"

#Test code
get_last_name()
print "All exceptions caught! Good job!"
print "The actor's last name is %s" % get_last_name()
```

where `――――――` represents a tab, and `·` a space. I've intentionally represented the tab as 6 characters wide, because 4 is only the convention *your* editor is using. Either use tabs or spaces for indentation, but *do not mix them!* PEP8 advocates spaces.

In this case, the problem is that the indentation of the `try` does not match that of the `except`

Answer (score 0):

I just copy and pasted your code and I get no errors which means it is likely a layout error. If you are using tabs try removing them and replacing them with 4 spaces.